# How to send push notifications to Ionic applications?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, ionic3

I am creating mobile application using latest version of Ionic 3. And I am at the point where I need to implement push notifications. I am using FCM. I have managed to done it for Android phones using this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push. Reading documentation for this plugin, it says that for Android I should send only Data Messages and that that is the best practice. It also says that send Notification and Data payload would not work properly:

> When your app is in the foreground any on('notification') handlers you have registered will be called. If your app is in the background, the notification will show up in the system tray. Clicking on the notification in the system tray will start the app and your on('notification') handler will not be called as messages that have notification payloads will not cause the plugins onMessageReceived method to be called.

But for IOS I need to send notification message with data payload. This would not be a problem if I target directly devices, however I need to send Topic Messages. So the way I see is  that on my server I need to implement this logic:

Let's say that the name of topic is `FOOD-AND-DRINKS`:

```
function onSomeEvent($data) {
    // send push notification to topic ANDROID~FOOD-AND-DRIKS        
    // send push notification to topic IOS~FOOD-AND-DRINKS
}
```

Also, since in the future my plan will include multiple cities, and not all people would like to listen for notifications for cities other the one where that person lives, so then my topic would be `PLATFORM~CITY~CATEGORY`.

So my question would be, is there any better plugin for handling notifications, or some service between my server and Google FCM and that service would take care of that, or this is quite OK what I have proposed?

Comment: yes this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: @PeterHaddad so, you are saying that logic for deciding how to send push notifications to put in one cloud function?

Comment: Im saying since you are already using FCM, then it is easier for u to use cloud functions also since there is no need for a server and it will be able to send notification in the background with data payload

Comment: did you understand what I mean? If not then tell me to be able to help you

Comment: @PeterHaddad I think I do, I am able to send push notifications with data payload to android device, I have working code on my server. However, the problem is that documentation in the plugin for Ionic says that my JS function would not be called if I send notification part and data payload on Android but I need to send them both for IOS to work... and also what is the best practice if I want to target devices by city, create seperate topics per city like `CITY-CATEGORY` or something else ...

Comment: if the answer helped please accept and upvote, so it will be easier for future readers to find it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud functions to be able to send notifications since you are using `FCM` also.

More on this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.

Using cloud functions you can use database triggers like `onWrite()` and it will be able to send notifications if you have data payload and/or notification.

But if you use data payload alone then you can send if android device is in background also.

**Regarding Topics:**

If you have multiple cities in your application, then you can let the user register to each topic. You can do in the database like this:

```
 city-category
          id_here
               cityname: nameX
               //other details
           id_here1
               cityname: nameY
               //other details
```